# Nivo Slider jumps in front of conditional "popped out" div

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

I am using a Nivo slider on my home page and have some hidden content that opens when you click on certain elements. I have a blackout div so that it greys out the main page and then the new content (which are various forms) show up on top. I recenlty changed my layout a little, so it used to work properly, but now, whenever I click to open the forms (the hidden divs) the nivo images are popping out in front of them. I've tried all sorts of z-index and positioning combinations, as well as using jquery to stop the nivo animation when the conditional divs are present, but nothing is really working. Perhaps I've done something incorrect.

Anyway, you can see the problem at www.caylena.com if you click on the button to sign up for the newsletter or free consult (both in navbar.)

Also, you can't seem to enter any content into the form anymore. I'm not sure what's happening. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Caylena,

I actually *don't* see the problem. I'm using Firefox 23.0.1 on Win7 and all is good - I can enter stuff in the forms, and the slider stops when the pop-up is on.

I had similar problem on the page I am developing. `z-index: 0;` applied to the slider-wrapper worked for me (other elements had higher z's).